# rails implementing deleted attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a form that has many contacts. I want to be able to delete contacts without really deleting them, but marking them deleted. I have added an attribute "deleted" to my contacts table.

In most cases I want a forms contacts I want only the ones that are not deleted:

```
form.contacts.find_all_by_deleted(false)
```

This seems messy, so I was thinking of a named_scope or a default_scope, but lots of people seem to say they are evil.

I also thought of just changing the relationship on the form to be (Is this the same as a default scope? Is it evil?):

```
has_many :contacts, :conditions => ["deleted = false"]
```

In my admin view I need to be able to see all contacts. I guess i can just do a find from the Contacts side adding the id of the form.

Seems like this is something that people would implement lots and there must be a well agreed to best practice.

Any solution must work in Rails 2 and not be obsolete for Rails 3. Prefer no plugin or gem.

Comment: Why do you prefer to not use a gem? Why would you rather implement your own code, which is more work, less tested, and less featureful? http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_soft_delete.html

Comment: Hi Ryeguy, gems are great if they bring significant value, but the downside is maintainability of code. For one class for 1 problem adding a gem seems overkill for me. If I wanted this on all my models it would probably be worth it. Lots of gems are ill maintained, moving from rails versions breaks them, they cause unintended consequences. We plan to have this codebase very widely deployed, so we are trying to keep the dependencies to a minimum whenever possible. Looking at KandadaBoggus suggestions below, this seems like 2 lines of code vs another gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: Associations:**

```
class User
  has_many :active_contacts, :class_name => "Contact", 
                            :conditions => {:deleted => false}
  has_many :contacts 
end
```

In your admin controller use the `contacts` association, every where else use the `active_contacts` association.

**Approach 2: default_scope:**

```
class User
  has_many :contacts 
end

class Contact
  default_scope {:conditions => {:deleted => false}}
end
```

For Regular users:

```
u.contacts
```

For admin users:

```
User.send(:with_exclusive_scope){u.contacts}
```

I have used default_scope for excluding `deleted` records. People are skittish about `default_scope` for a good reason as sometimes it can cause unintended behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You are acting like a paranoid :-)
http://ar-paranoid.rubyforge.org/